# C# assign a variable with x number of spaces

Tags: c#, string

I am creating a fixed length flat file header, but the last portion of the header is reserved for future use. That means it needs to contain over 1k blank spaces.

I have created a model that breaks up each part of the header, but I need to find a way to assign such a large number of spaces to the last variable. I cannot put that number of spaces inside double quotes. Is there a method or process out there to create a string based on the character and number of times?

Comment: How about our old n' good `for` loop?

Comment: So are you creating a new string with X number of spaces, or are you adding X spaces to an existing string?

Comment: It was created from scratch, not adding. I got the answer below. Thank you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Good:

```
var spacer = new String(' ', 1000);
```

Ridiculous:

```
var spacer2 = String.Join("", Enumerable.Range(0, 1000).Select(n => ' '));
```

A cleaner ridiculous one (thanks to the not-at-all-perfidious Abion47):

```
var spacer3 = new string(Enumerable.Repeat(' ', 1000).ToArray());
```

But if you want to pad the header *to* some arbitrary final width, Abion47's suggestion of `PadRight()` would be best in that case, because you don't have to waste time fiddling around with subtraction: `PadRight()`'s int parameter is the desired total width of the result.

Comment: I knew it was something basic I was overlooking. Thank you!

Comment: A slightly better "ridiculous" would be `new string(Enumerable.Repeat(' ', 1000).ToArray());`

Comment: Also it's `Abion`. No "L". :P

Answer (score 4):

You can use `PadRight`:

```
int totalStringLength = 500;
string paddedString = sourceString.PadRight(totalStringLength, ' ');
```

This will make `sourceString`'s length equal to `totalStringLength`, adding as many spaces to the end of it as necessary to make it so.

Comment: Thank you for this. This is perfect for the data portion of my code where there is much more fluctuation in what will be entered.

Answer (score 1):

It is simple. Use this

```
string sSpaces = new String(' ', 100);
```

Of course, you can replace 100 with any number you want.

Hope it helps.